# Get information from facet command in mongo BD

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to extract a list of names from a pipeline, where I get the following:

```
 command_5 = {"$facet": {
        "list_of_station_names": my_query_1}}
```

And get as result:

```
list_of_station_names  :  [{'desc': 'Sip Ave'}, {'desc': 'Vesey Pl &; River Terrace'}, {'desc': 'Murray St &; West St'},{'desc': 'E 81 St &; York Ave'}]
```

but I need the results in a list without the attribute name "desc", like this:

```
 list_of_station_names  :  ['Sip Ave', 'Vesey Pl &; River Terrace','Murray St &; West St','E 81 St &; York Ave']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only map it after facet.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      list_of_station_names: []
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      list_of_station_names: {
        $map: {
          input: "$list_of_station_names",
          as: "n",
          in: "$$n.desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HKYGIG4usoG)